# How to assert a json property which can be either null(Porp:null) or has a sub schema(Porp:{ denyAny: '#boolean', assertions: '#[]' }) In KARATE DSL?

Tags: karate

I have a Json payload to validate. And It has a property which can be either null or a sub json object. But this property exists in the json.

I tried following methods:
01

```js
And def dnyAssertionSchema =  { denyAny: '#boolean', assertions: '##[]' }

And match each policyGResponse ==
    """
    { 

      denyAssertions: '##(dnyAssertionSchema)'
    }
    """
```

AND

```js
And match each policyGResponse ==
    """
    { 

      denyAssertions: '##null dnyAssertionSchema'

    }
    """
```

AND

- This does not work as the property is not an array so I tried above second method even I couldn't find an example as such.

And match each policyGResponse ==
          """
          {

```
        denyAssertions: '##[] dnyAssertionSchema'

      }
      """
```

**The Actual response can be either**

```js
 { 

      denyAssertions=null

    }
```

**OR**

```js
 { 

      denyAssertions={ denyAny: true, assertions: ["a","b"] }

    }
```

I use Karate 0.9.1
Error message I get is 'reason: actual value has 1 more key(s) than expected: {denyAssertions=null}' in first try

In second try I get 'assertion failed: path: $[3].denyAssertions, actual: {denyAny=false, assertions=[]}, expected: '##null dnyAssertionSchema', reason: not equal'

Comment: Hi @Peter, I edited the question and highlighted 'Actual response'. Sorry for ill formatted question. Could you look at it please?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is *still* not valid but anyway. Here you go:

```
* def schema = { denyAny: '#boolean', assertions: '#[]' }
* def response1 = { denyAssertions: { denyAny: true, assertions: ["a","b"] } }
* match response1 == { denyAssertions: '##(schema)' }

* def response2 = { denyAssertions: null }
* match response1 == { denyAssertions: '##(schema)' }
```

Comment: Hi @Peter, I tried the solution, Thank you. It worked as a single assertion. But when I tried using it in Schema validation It did not work. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: @ChaminiKumara I have no idea what you are saying. please ask another question if needed ! and you can use the above as a reference to simplify your question next time so that it needs only 5 lines max

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do this https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/schema-like.feature

Comment: @ChaminiKumara all the best !